# Best way to generate a UUID in PHP without using external libraries

Tags: php, uuid

I know there are tools like https://github.com/ramsey/uuid to generate UUID's but i dont use composer and would like to generate a UUID's in my login controller.

Comment: Open library code and copy-paste it?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php - check out the exaples here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this:

It uses random bytes and puts them in the right positions by using the vsprintf function.

[Random bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)

```
$UUID = vsprintf( '%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)), 4) );
```